# Concatenating 2 columns

Tags: vba, concatenation

Good day,

Looking for help if my concatenating code. I am trying to concatenate Column E & G in sheet1, into column B in sheet2.

There is already data on sheet2, so I am trying to get it to copy the data onto the last row of sheet 2.

It is only concatenating the last Row in sheet 1, and not being placed in the correct spot.

Thank you in advance

```
Dim LastRowOutput As Long
    LastRowOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value <> "")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & (LastRowOutput + 1)).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("G" & i).Value & "," & _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E" & i).Value
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

This is the result I get:

Sheet1

```
ID  First Name  Last Name    
1   John        Doe    
2   Joe         Smith    
3   Bob         Sled
```

Sheet2

```
Employee #  Employee name    
0           St Nick    
1           Sled,Bob    
2       
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place your values into an array first, concatenate them there, then assign the values back to your worksheet. This would be much quicker than doing it line-by-line.

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    'Place your cells into an array
    Dim valE() As Variant, valG() As Variant
    valE = ws1.UsedRange.Columns("E").Value
    valG = ws1.UsedRange.Columns("G").Value

    'Merge into a new 2-D array
    Dim retArr() As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim retArr(2 To UBound(valE))
    For i = 2 To UBound(valE)
        retArr(i) = valE(i, 1) & valG(i, 1)
    Next

    'determine the start and end rows to add data to
    Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
    lngStart = NextRow(ws2, "B")
    lngEnd = UBound(retArr) + lngStart - LBound(retArr)

    ws2.Range("B" & lngStart & ":B" & lngEnd) = Application.Transpose(retArr)

End Sub

Function NextRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better code.

Since sheet 2 will already contain data, I'm hoping to get this to transpose over to sheet2 from the last row that it left off. B3 technically in this case. 

I imagine I will need to set up a lastrow variable for B and incorporate it somehow into this transpose line?

ws2.Range("B2:B" & UBound(retArr)) = Application.Transpose(retArr)

Comment: @Chris updated code. See if that's what you're looking for

Comment: This work perfectly. Many thanks for taking the time to show me! 
I'll need to spend some time to study this to see how you approached it.  :)